# C4172 and C4239 returning local variable

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, local-variables

I've got a function to normalize a Vec2D.  I recieve both C4172 and C4239 errors.  I understand that I should not return local variables, but I don't understand what I should return instead.  Should I make it a pointer?
Method:

```
inline Vec2D& normalize()const {
    double l = length();
    if (x == 0) {
        if (y == 0) {
            return Vec2D(0, 0);
        }
        else {
            return Vec2D(0, y / l);
        }
    }
    else if (y == 0) {
        return Vec2D(x / l, 0);
    }
    return Vec2D(x / l, y / l);
}
```

Comment: any reason to return by reference (`Vec2D&`) not value (`Vec2D`)?

Comment: who says not to return local variables (by value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to return local variables, by value. What you should not do, is return them by reference. Drop the `&` from the return type.

```
inline Vec2D normalize()const {
    ...
```

Comment: Wait, so if I drop the `&` then it'd be fine to store a public variable as `normalize()`?

Comment: @Tips48: You'll have to rephrase that. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: I store the result of `normalize` as a global variable.  Will the variable become invalid or stay in scope? (If that makes sense)

Comment: @Tips48: Yes, it's fine, the global will not become invalid.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I didn't understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably implement it as:

```
inline void normalize(Vec2D* vect) const {
    ....
```

like this, the user of the function could provide a `Vec2D` from the stack, from the heap, and even a derived class with base `Vect2D`. Performance is good because no copying is involved.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an attempt to return a reference to a **temporary** object (which is also local) - `Vec2D` returns an object to your function, but you're not storing it anywhere, just returning a reference to it, which becomes dangling once you move to the next instruction in the code. While in this case the effect is similar to returning a reference to a local variable, it's important to understand the difference. Local variable will become invalid on exit from function and temporary variable will become invalid on the next instruction.